# Synchronize data lake with the deleted record

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, cassandra, hdfs, data-lake

I am building data lake to integrate multiple data sources for advanced analytics.

In the begining, I select HDFS as data lake storage. But I have a requirement for updates and deletes in data sources which I have to synchronise with data lake.

To understand the immutable nature of Data Lake I will consider LastModifiedDate from Data source to detect that this record is updated and insert this record in Data Lake with a current date. The idea is to select the record with max(date).

However, I am not able to understand how

1. I will detect deleted records from sources and what I will do with Data Lake?
2. Should I use other data storage like Cassandra and execute a delete command? I am afraid it will lose the immutable property.

can you please suggest me good practice for this situation?

Answer (score 1):

#### 1. Question - Detecting deleted records from datasources

Detecting deleted records from data sources, requires that your data sources supports this. Best is that deletion is only done logically, e. g. with a change flag. For some databases it is possible to track also deleted rows (see for example for [SQL-Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/track-changes/manage-change-tracking-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017)). Also some ETL solutions like Informatica offer CDC (Changed Data Capture) capabilities.

#### 2. Question - Changed data handling in a big data solution

There are different approaches. Of cause you can use a key value store adding some kind of complexity to the overall solution. First you have to clarify, if it is also of interest to track changes and deletes. You could consider loading all data (new/changed/deleted) into daily partitions and finally build an actual image (data as it is in your data source). Also consider solutions like Databricks Delta addressing this topics, without the need of an additional store. For example you are able to do an upsert on parquet files with delta as follows:

```
    MERGE INTO events
      USING updates
      ON events.eventId = updates.eventId
    WHEN MATCHED THEN
       UPDATE SET
       events.data = updates.data
    WHEN NOT MATCHED
       THEN INSERT (date, eventId, data) VALUES (date, eventId, data)
```

If your solution also requires low latency access via a key (e. g. to support an API) then a key-values store like HBase, Cassandra, etc. would be helpfull.

Answer (score 0):

Usually this is always a constraint while creating datalake in Hadoop, one can't just update or delete records in it. There is one approach that you can try is

1. When you are adding lastModifiedDate, you can also add one more column naming status. If a record is deleted, mark the status as Deleted. So the next time, when you want to query the latest active records, you will be able to filter it out.
2. You can also use cassandra or Hbase (any nosql database), if you are performing ACID operations on a daily basis. If not, first approach would be your ideal choice for creating datalake in Hadoop